# Expansion of $f = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n} \frac{z^n}{1 - z^n}$ in power series around $z = 0$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

Let $f = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n} \frac{z^n}{1 - z^n}$, for $z \in \mathbb C \setminus ${$z \in \mathbb C: \exists n \geq 1,\quad  z^n = 1$}. By the ratio test, the series converges when $|z|< 1$ and $|z|> 1$. I'm trying to find the expantion of $f$ in power series around $z=0$.

What I did until now:

Let $|z| < \delta < 1$.

$$ \frac{z^n}{1 - z^n} = z^n \frac{1}{1-z^n} = z^n (1+ z^n + z^{2n} + ... ) = z^n + z^{2n} + z^{3n}$$

Then

$$ \frac{z^n}{1 - z^n} = z^n + z^{2n} + z^{3n} \Rightarrow a_n = \frac{1}{2^n} \sum_{k=1}^\infty z^{k n}, \forall n \geq 1$$

Then,

$$f(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n} \sum_{k=1}^\infty z^{k n} $$

How May I conclude the question?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $n = 1$, $(1/2) (z + z^2 + z^3 + z^4 + ...)$

If $n = 2$, $(1/2^2) (z^2 + z^4 + z^6 + ... )$

If $n = 3$, $(1/2^3) (z^3 + z^6 + z^9 + ....)$

So, 
$$ f = \frac{1}{2} z + (\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2^2} ) z^2 + (\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2^3})z^3 + (\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{2^4}) z^4 + (\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2^5})z^5 + (\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{2^3} + \frac{1}{2^6}) z^6 + ...$$

By induction, we have $f = \sum b_n z^n$, where $b_n = \sum_{k | n} \frac{1}{2^k} $